# how to resolve the "Error in method main. java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError"?

Tags: java

```
    static WebAppAccess webAppAccess;
    static 
    {

        String userId = webAppAccess.getVariables().getString(
        "moduleSelect_var");

        if(userId.equals("set"))
```

for above code i am geetting the error like this

```
The error message returned was: "Error in method main. java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError".
```

Please refer to the logs folder in your deployed application for additional error information.

Click here to hide the detailed error message.

```
Exception Error in method main. java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError

Stack Trace
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java(Compiled Code))
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java(Compiled Code))
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java(Compiled Code))
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance3(Class.java(Compiled Code))
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java(Compiled Code))
    at com.bowstreet.webapp.structures.VariableUtil.instantiateObjectValue(VariableUtil.java:203)
    at com.bowstreet.webapp.structures.RuntimeVariableImpl.getVariableValue(RuntimeVariableImpl.java:371)
    at com.bowstreet.webapp.structures.RuntimeVariableImpl.getValue(RuntimeVariableImpl.java:126)
    at com.bowstreet.webapp.structures.VariablesImpl.getVariableValue(VariablesImpl.java:584)
    at com.bowstreet.webapp.structures.VariablesImpl.getObject(VariablesImpl.java:388)
    at com.bowstreet.webapp.engine.actions.MethodAction.getMethodClassInstance(MethodAction.java:163)
    at com.bowstreet.webapp.engine.actions.MethodAction.callAction(MethodAction.java:86)
    at com.bowstreet.webapp.engine.WebAppAccessImpl.callMethod(WebAppAccessImpl.java:405)
    at genjava._qwe.main(_qwe.java:98)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java(Compiled Code))
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java(Compiled Code))
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java(Compiled Code))
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java(Compiled Code))
    at com.bowstreet.webapp.engine.actions.MethodAction.callAction(MethodAction.java:90)
    at com.bowstreet.webapp.engine.WebAppAccessImpl.callMethod(WebAppAccessImpl.java:405)
    at com.bowstreet.webapp.engine.WebAppAccessImpl.processAction(WebAppAccessImpl.java:1046)
    at com.bowstreet.webapp.engine.WebAppAccessImpl.processAction(WebAppAccessImpl.java:1146)
    at com.bowstreet.webapp.engine.WebAppRequestRunner.doRequest(WebAppRequestRunner.java:364)
    at com.bowstreet.webapp.engine.WebAppRunner.doActualRequest(WebAppRunner.java:866)
    at com.bowstreet.webapp.engine.WebAppRunner.doRequest(WebAppRunner.java:526)
    at com.bowstreet.webapp.engine.WebAppRunner.doRequest(WebAppRunner.java:291)
    at com.bowstreet.webapp.engine.WebAppRunner.doRequest(WebAppRunner.java:228)
    at com.bowstreet.webapp.engine.WebAppServlet.doPost(WebAppServlet.java:73)
    at com.bowstreet.webapp.engine.WebAppServlet.doGet(WebAppServlet.java:53)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:595)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:688)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:252)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:173)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:213)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:178)
    at org.apache.geronimo.tomcat.valve.DefaultSubjectValve.invoke(DefaultSubjectValve.java:56)
    at org.apache.geronimo.tomcat.GeronimoStandardContext$SystemMethodValve.invoke(GeronimoStandardContext.java:342)
    at org.apache.geronimo.tomcat.valve.GeronimoBeforeAfterValve.invoke(GeronimoBeforeAfterValve.java:31)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:126)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:105)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:541)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.SingleSignOn.invoke(SingleSignOn.java:392)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:148)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:869)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11BaseProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.processConnection(Http11BaseProtocol.java:667)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.PoolTcpEndpoint.processSocket(PoolTcpEndpoint.java:527)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.LeaderFollowerWorkerThread.runIt(LeaderFollowerWorkerThread.java:80)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPool$ControlRunnable.run(ThreadPool.java:869)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:570)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.grpf.OuterClass.(OuterClass.java:28)
    ... 52 more
```

Comment: Your `webAppAccess` is `null`. What do you expect?

Answer (score 0):

You call a method on `webAppAccess` when it is still null, s you get a `NullPointerException`:

```
static WebAppAccess webAppAccess;
static 
{

    String userId = webAppAccess.getVariables().getString("moduleSelect_var");
    //              ^ here it is still null

    if(userId.equals("set"))
```

Assign an object to it first to solve it:

```
static WebAppAccess webAppAccess;
static 
{
    webAppAccess = new WebAppAccess(); // or whatever the constructor is...
    String userId = webAppAccess.getVariables().getString("moduleSelect_var");

    if(userId.equals("set"))
```

Comment: now i am getting error likeAn error has occurred.
The error message returned was: "Error in method main. Unresolved compilation problem: Cannot instantiate the type WebAppAccess ".

Comment: I have never used `WebAppAccess` before, only addressed your problem which have nothing to do with this specific class. Check the documentation how to get a `WebAppAccess` instance..